# How to make Internet facing SharePoint website to cater different geographical locations?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, site-collection, localization, custom-masterpage, internet-sites

I have a SharePoint Foundation hosting account. I want to provide SharePoint to private teams through an Internet facing site. There needs to be a selector page at the root domain where users can choose their location to get directed to the local SharePoint site, where they can login. I am planning to use a folder hierarchy for locations. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The tasks involved in making a internet facing SharePoint site depends on what you need:

At a minimum you should:

- Get a DNS entry pointing to your site, how you get that set up depends on your hoster
- Enable anonymous access to the site. [Here](http://www.sharepointkris.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=2) is the full process, but you may not have the rights to do the central admin part, so again you may need your hosters help

And the you probably want to:

- Create a custom master page to make your site look "not like sharepoint". There is some starting points [here](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2011/09/09/just-the-essentials-sharepoint-master-pages/), [here](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) and [here](http://spmasterpage.codeplex.com/). But it very much depends on you needs and HTML/CSS skills.
- Develop some content to put on the pages.

In general I'd not recommend using SharePoint Foundation for public facing sites, unless you have good SharePoint knowledge or have a lot of content/skills around SharePoint that you need to reuse in your public facing site. SharePoint was build as a collaboration platform not a CMS.
SharePoint Server has a lot more CMS capabilities, but at least in the current version I'd only use it for public facing sites if I had content/skills that I'd want to reuse.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The links for the master pages should be very helpful and I will check them out. But my question was not complete enough earlier. I have now edited it to reflect what I really want to achieve. Will appreciate some more guidance.

Comment: With your new question I'd create each team site as a seperate site collection. On the root site collection is the only one I'd set to allow annonoymous access and I should only have a page with a web part to redirect users to the right site collection.

Comment: Okay. I do want the sites to be interlinked in the hierarchy. For example, I would like a COUNTRY site to be able to show list of users from the child STATE sites. The WORLDWIDE site should be able to access data from all the COUNTRY sites but should be accessible only through a separate admin url. And so I am looking for a way to create this with a single site collection.